# How can I change highlighted text programically in wxpython ListBox

Tags: python, wxpython

I can't really explain what I mean so I'm going to show it in html

```js
var c = 0;
    function getSong() {
        if (c>=3) {
            c=0
        }
        c++;
        if (c==1) {
            document.getElementById("3").style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
        document.getElementById(""+c-1).style.backgroundColor = "white";
        document.getElementById(""+c).style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
    window.setInterval(function() {getSong()}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="0">Song Change Automatic Change In ListBox</div>
<div style="border: 1px black solid; height: 150px; width: 100px;">
    <p id="1" style="border: 1px black solid; width: 100px;">Song 1</p>
    <p id="2" style="border: 1px black solid; width: 100px;">Song 2</p>
    <p id="3" style="border: 1px black solid; width: 100px;">Song 3</p>
</div>
```

The div represents the ListBox song 1 /song 3 represents the songs changing and highlighting the next song once completed.  Is this possible in wxPython?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with `ListBox` but you can change item attributes with `ListCtrl`. It allows you to set a `wx.ListItemAttr` for the items in the list control, and in the attr object you can set things like fg, bg colors and font. If you use the `wx.LC_REPORT` and `wx.LC_NO_HEADER` styles then it will look and mostly act like a `ListBox`.